# How can I have a line break display when displaying a string?

Tags: reactjs

I am importing a string from an api to display on a web page using react. 
The contents of the string is: "Name \n Last Name". How do I get React to display the line break contained in the string?

I am able to change to change the contents of the string on the backend of the api. I have tried both "\n" and the br tag, but neither seem to work.

My react code looks like this:

```
<div className="definition">
  {this.state.definition}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two** ways you could solve this issue:

**1.** Split the text you receive before rendering.

:

```
let newText = text.split('\n').map((item, i) => {
 return <p key={i}>{item}</p>;
});
```

**2.** Use **white-space: pre-wrap;**

:

```
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/yuzu-r/pen/wobaMR

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style `style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}`